# .htaccess - How to deny all directories except one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this structure:

```
 /folder/public/
 /folder/text.txt
 /folder/app/
 (etc...)
```

I want visitors to access to /public/ except everything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block everything except /folder/public/
RewriteRule !^folder/public/ - [F,NC]
```